# React Invalid Hook Call While Working With Stripe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I'm implementing stripe payment to my website so I'm reading stripe payment docs. [The Stripe payment document I'm following.](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder)
I even copied and pasted the code but I'm still having

`Invalid Hooks Error`.

I have two files one is checkoutPayment.js other one is stripeCheckoutForm.js

**In stripeCheckoutForm.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

export default function CheckoutForm() {
  const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  useEffect(() => {
    window
      .fetch("/create-payment-intent", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt" }] }),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
      });
  }, []);

  const cardStyle = {
    style: {
      base: {
        color: "#32325d",
        fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif",
        fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
        fontSize: "16px",
        "::placeholder": {
          color: "#32325d",
        },
      },
      invalid: {
        color: "#fa755a",
        iconColor: "#fa755a",
      },
    },
  };

  const handleChange = async (event) => {
    setDisabled(event.empty);
    setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
      },
    });

    if (payload.error) {
      setError(`Payment failed ${payload.error.message}`);
      setProcessing(false);
    } else {
      setError(null);
      setProcessing(false);
      setSucceeded(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <CardElement
        id="card-element"
        options={cardStyle}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded} id="submit">
        <span id="button-text">
          {processing ? (
            <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div>
          ) : (
            "Pay now"
          )}
        </span>
      </button>
      {error && (
        <div className="card-error" role="alert">
          {error}
        </div>
      )}
      <p className={succeeded ? "result-message" : "result-message hidden"}>
        Payment succeeded, see the result in your
        <a href={`https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments`}>
          Stripe dashboard.
        </a>
        Refresh the page to pay again.
      </p>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**In checkoutPayment.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CheckoutForm from "./stripeCheckoutForm";

const promise = loadStripe("pk_test_6XtghloNmnIJt2Bov5bGRCAg00ozfbAMRE");
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Elements stripe={promise}>
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My error is:**

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. 
This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem
```

Comment: What is your version of react-dom? You can log it out by doing `console.log(React.version);` Have you walked through the debugging steps here: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: @hmunoz I go throguh steps thank you. My problem is react duplication. How can I solve this why this happened?

Comment: @hmunoz I have other files and I use hooks too but I don't get this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's so funny. It's just because of I forgot to install npm packages correctly.

```
npm install @stripe/react-stripe-js

npm install @stripe/stripe-js
```

Installing the packages resolved the problem.